# How to build a portable absolute path in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Let's assume a script needs access a directory, say `/some/where/abc` on an "arbitrary" OS. There are a couple options to build the path in Ruby:

- `File.join('', 'some', 'where', 'abc')`
- `File.absolute_path("some#{File::SEPARATOR}where#{File::SEPARATOR}abc", File::SEPARATOR)`
- `Pathname` in the standard API

I believe the first solution is clear enough, but idiomatic. In my experience, some code reviews ask for a comment to explain what it does...

**The Question**

Is there a better way to build an absolute path is Ruby, where better means "does the job and speaks for itself"?

Comment: I'd just link the doc in the code review. It explicitly says "Returns a new string formed by joining the strings using File::SEPARATOR." `File#join` is the usual way to produce portable paths.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "arbitrary OS", `"tmp/abc/"` as a string literal is a valid path on Linux, Mac, and Windows.

Comment: The documentation, or just the intended path as a comment, works well. Just trying to find hidden or forgotten spells in Ruby.

Comment: Charles, correct. The question is really about absolute paths.

Comment: @EricPlaton I read your example path wrong but the same works for absolute paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would pick up if I was doing a code review is that on Windows `/tmp` is not necessarily the best place to create a temporary directory, and also the initial `'',` argument is perhaps not obvious to the casual reviewed that it creates `<nothing>/tmp/abc`. Therefore, I would recommend this code:

```
File.join(Dir.tmpdir(), 'abc')
```

See [Ruby-doc for an explanation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html#method-c-tmpdir).

**UPDATE**

If we expand the problem to a more generic solution that does not involve using `tmpdir()`, I cannot see a way round using the initial `''` idiom (hack?). On Linux this is not too much of a problem, perhaps, but on Windows with multiple drive letters it will be. Furthermore, there does not appear to be a Ruby API or gem for iterating the mount points.

Therefore, my recommendation would be to delegate the mount point definition to a configuration option that might be `'/'` for Linux, `'z:/'` for Windows, and `smb://domain;user@my.file.server.com/mountpoint` for a Samba share, then use `File.join(ProjectConfig::MOUNT_POINT, 'some', 'where', 'abc')`.

Comment: Good catch on the tmpdir. This is even more portable and also better reflects the intent. +1

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Excellent to address my particular problem. I do not mark the question as answered yet. Let's see if someone has a good idea for the general problem (now realizing that `/tmp` lead the question to an unexpected way).

Comment: @Eric I see you reworded the question! I've had a think and a look around, and I can't see a general solution to what makes me most uncomfortable, the leading `''`. There seems to be no generic way to iterate mount points, such as getting the `c:/` for Windows or a Samba mount point on Linux, etc. Perhaps delegating the mount point definition to a configuration option is the best compromise and using `File.join(ProjectConfig::MOUNT_POINT, 'foo', 'bar')`?

Comment: Yes, Ken. The question itself (title) was generic, though. My example with `/tmp` has restricted it too much, so my edit (see the edit log). Tell me what you think: Accepting this answer is misleading. How about creating or editing the answer with your latest comment. I would prefer to accept a response that does not rely on comments to be understood by readers. Still wondering if there is no way to address this issue! I'll try harder :-)

Comment: @KenY-N, thanks for the follow up, and sorry for the late acceptance. The problem has some kind of solution, yet not feeling satisfied!

Answer (score 2):

`File#join` is THE canonical way to build a portable path in Ruby. I'm wondering who is doing the review. Perhaps Ruby is new to your organization.

I agree with @ChrisHeald that referring to the documentation is the best way to explain the code to a reviewer.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with all the comments so far, so +1. File#join is my preferred approach, but relies on an idiom. The question is really about "showing off" a better way to address this problem (if any)---the review is just settings to illustrate what can happen.